# Make calculation from v-for in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i'm trying to make simple calculation from data given in vuejs. The calculation is just going well. But, when i started to make sum from calculation total from it, it keeps returning NaN value.

Here is the current code of it:

```html
<div class="row" v-for="fields in data" :key="field.id_m_all_ded">
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>{{ field.name }}</label>
      <input type="field.type" class="form-control" @change="calculated(field)" v-model="field.value" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-7">
    <label>Total Deductions</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" v-model="field.total" disabled />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <label>Total Allowance</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" v-model="grandTotal" id="total" disabled />
  </div>
</div>
```

I retrieve the data from my API, and it saved in fields[]:

```js
data() {
  return {
    model: {
      nik: "",
      name: "",
      basic_salary: "",
      period: "",
    },
    modals: {
      modal: false,
    },
    fields: [{
      total: ''
    }],
    totalData: 11,
    page: 1,
    mode: "",
  };
},
```

And here's the function:

```js
computed: {
  grandTotal: function() {
    let temp = 0
    for (var i = 0; i < this.fields.length; i++) {
      temp = temp + Number(this.fields[i].total)
      console.log(temp)
    }
    console.log(temp)
    return temp;
  }
}, 
methods: {
  calculated(field){
    field.total = 4000000 * (field.value / 100)
    console.log(field.total)
  }
}
```

For addtional info, i get the data from the api, but it won't calculate automatic. Therefore, i tried it with manual input first to calculate the value.

What code should i fix from it, because i have no clue.

Thanks

Comment: `I retrieve the data from my API, and it saved in fields[]:` show an example of the data - it's probably not an array of objects with a `total` property that is a number - considering you create the `total` property in `calculated`

Comment: Instead of for loop can you try `this.fields.reduce((acc, obj) => acc + Number(obj.total), 0);`

Comment: also try `(Number(this.fields[i].total) || 0)`

Comment: @Syed that won't fix anything

Comment: can you show us the `data` that you are using `v-for="fields in data"`

Comment: @Syed The data from fields.value are {4, 3.7, 2.5, 5, 1, 2}

Comment: @JaromandaX it doesn't work neither :)

Comment: For info, i get the data from the api, but it won't calculate automatic. Therefore, i tried it with manual input first

Comment: @jutrey, let's fix it call me on skype: syed_haroon

Comment: also, check for plural in `fields` (s) in `v-for="fields in youData"`, `fields` need to be `field`

Comment: Can we do it in 30 minutes later?

Comment: try `grandTotal: function() {
    return this.fields.reduce((acc, field) => acc + this.calculated(field), 0);
}`

Comment: @jutrey, in 30 mins okay, hope you have tried `v-for="field in fields"` or `v-for="field in orWhateverYouNamedIt"`?

Comment: wouldn't `v-for="fields in data" :key="field.id_m_all_ded"` cause an error since you don't have data called data? and you're saying for fields in data then trying to access field (no s)???

Comment: Personally, I'd calculate the `total` property for each `field` in `fields` at the point where you retrieve `the data from my API, and it saved in fields[]:`

Comment: I get the data in created:, and put the data [] for the container @JaromandaX

Comment: whatever ... that's the point I'd calculate totals at that point - but, whatever

Comment: Sorry, i just don't get it yet what's your saying. Can you explain it? @JaromandaX